# What are the following words called: Am, Is, Are, Was, Were, Be, Being, Been?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> Am, Is, Are, Was, Were, Be, Being, Been

What are the above words called? I think someone called them auxiliary verbs.

**Edit:** When I learned them, my curriculum called them "State of Being verbs" or just "Being verbs".

Comment: And why does everyone always learn them in that order? Except the weird ones who do "be, been, being".

Comment: For the record, some of us weird ones learned "Am, Are, Is, Was, Were, Be, Being, Been."

Comment: Some of these answers are so metaphysical; we should probably have some Heidegger expert weigh in on this

Comment: I learned them in the same order as the OP, but kitukwfyer's order makes grammatical sense: 1st person, 2nd person, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The words you cited are all forms of the verb “be”, which is also known as a *[copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics))* or *linking verb*.

The term [*auxiliary verb*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) applies to verbs, such as forms of *be*, *have*, and *do*, that conjoin with another verb to add syntactic or semantic information, such as [grammatical aspects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) like the progressive aspect or perfective aspect:

- progressive aspect: *be* + present participle (e.g. *am walking*)
- perfective aspect: *have* + past participle (e.g. *have walked*)

Verbs such as *will* and *shall* combine to indicate future tense or conditional tense.

Comment: Note, it's not always the copula, and *be* isn't the only copula in English.

Comment: Many linguists in modern times use a slightly different definition of "auxiliary" when talking about words in English that does not require the presence of another verb. You can see an overview in this slideshow by Geoff Pullum: http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/aux_sli.pdf If auxiliaries are defined, as Pullum argues, by the "NICE" properties, then "be" is basically always an auxiliary, even when it takes a noun or adjective phrase as a complement.

Answer (score 9):

And, to add to the terminology conundrum:

"to be" is either

- a copula verb: it asserts a property

  > John is a teacher
  >
  > Peter is nice
- an auxiliary verb: it is required to encode, e.g., tense or voice

  > Max has been beaten up by members of this gang
- a full-blown main verb: roughly meaning "to exist"

  > To be or not to be: that is the question

These distinctions can become quite fuzzy. Consider:

> There is a unicorn in the garden

Is this the "exist"-reading of the verb, or is it copula use? I currently have no definite answer for this.

Comment: my guess is that its like this... noun+prepositional phrase. copula usage when referring to the who, what, where; main verb as in existence only when used as a declarative of noun+verb ie 'A unicorn is' (and disregarding the prep. phrase).

Answer (score 6):

Those are just forms of the verb *to be*. *To be* is just one of the auxiliary verbs in English (and it's not always an auxiliary). Others are:

```
have
has
had
do
does
did
shall
will
should
would
may
might
must
can
could
```

Answer (score 3):

*To be* is an auxiliary verb; *am*, *is*, *are*, *was*, *were*, *being*, *been* are different tenses of the verb.

Answer (score 0):

**Kiamlaluno's** answer is the closest to my understanding - And though **mfg** mentions Heidegger, Plato and Aristotle were the source of original Ontological dialogues of *being qua being.* "I am that you were." states tenses of the abstract qualities of being. The sentence is awkward and seems to be too truncated, but it is actually has correct usage of the 'being' tenses reflected in both 'am' and 'were'. The distinction reads as, "I **am** *(present reference being)* that you **were** (past reference being). With this distinction, **Am, Is, Are, Was, Were, Be, Being, Been** can be considered as *referential verbs*. In context; [referential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference) *Referential / Reference is a relation between objects in which one object designates, or acts as a means by which to connect to or link to, another object. The first object in this relation is said to refer to the second object.*"